# Can't update or delete an R package from a private repo on Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I currently have a private git repo R package installed on Ubuntu. I’ve made changes to the package on a git branch, built the package and installed it from the git repo after checking out the branch with

```
install.packages("~/package_repo",
                 repos = NULL,
                 type = "source",
                 clean = TRUE)
```

I restarted R and reloaded the package. I can use the new functions I created, but the old functions that already existed are not updated and none of the functions I deleted have been removed.

I figured R installed the package in two different places and they are conflicting now, so checked `.libPaths` on the machine and went into

```
/usr/lib/R/library/{package_name}
```

and deleted the folder containing the package. However, that didn’t help. I can still load the package and the old functions are in place even though the package doesn’t exist in that folder anymore even after restarting R.

How can this be?

To sanity check, I tried repeating this process on a Mac machine, and the package was updated without problems.

Comment: Are you loading an `.Rdata` file in your R session? When you start R, did `ls()` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

I found the package was also installed in `/home/default_user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6`.

After deleting it from there and reinstalling the package worked fine.